# Bug with withinMiles in parse.com javascript geo queries api

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I think I've found a bug in the pasre.com javascript Geo Queries API. I'm constructing a query like so:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
query.near("center", parseLocation);
query.withinMiles(15.0);
query.limit(10);
return query.find().then(function (locations) { ... });
```

When I execute this query I get the following error:

```
Failed location lookup: 102 $maxDistance needs float
```

And when I remove the `withinMiles` line it works fine. I'm basing my code on [this documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#geo-query); any ideas if I'm somehow misusing the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change request:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
query.withinMiles("center", parseLocation, 15);
query.limit(10);
return query.find().then(function (locations) { ... });
```